# Is there a way to validate the syntax of regex pattern using C code

Tags: c

The regex pattern  is :

[image]

However its not a valid pattern as the syntax is wrong (there should be a . preceding * in 2 places)

Correct pattern is :

[image]

Is there a way to validate the syntax of these regex patterns in C programming?
Any library or function which would evaluate the above wrong pattern and return invalid pattern?
I tried using regcomp (but it did not return invalid pattern for the wrong input)

Comment: regex are not a part of the C language, so you would need to find an external library.

Comment: This would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/3643454/10035556

Comment: regcomp did not return invalid pattern for the wrong input which i have provided

Comment: which library can be used to serve the purpose of validation?

Comment: Please don't include text as images. If anyone wants to copy that, they won't be able to

Comment: actually i pasted the original text, but few characters were not seen correctly after posting it

Comment: "Is there a way to do X in C"? Yes.

Comment: PIck a regular expression library. Use it to try to compile the expression, see if that succeeds or not. Note that if your RE is being stored as a string literal, you'll have to escape the backslashes in it so that they're treated as literal characters and not the start of a escape sequence themselves..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go overboard and do it in C with a library, or check out these live testing tools https://regex101.com/ or https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: I do not want to use live testing tools, it would be good if i can do the validation in code itself (C or C++)

Comment: @Person `C` or `C++` - pick one. `C++` has a `regex` library.

Comment: C is what i want, if there is no way out in C, then C++ is the second option.

Answer (score 0):

There are regex libraries for c you can use (see [Regular expressions in C: examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples) ). 
When you want to find out, if a given string has valid regex format, you can do this by using another regex ( see [Is there a regular expression to detect a valid regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression)), or you can try to "compile" the string as regex. I think the first way is the cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the regex implementation you're using. Here's an example using POSIX extended regular expressions that simply checks the return value of [`regcomp`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html) and prints an error message obtained with `regerror`:

```c
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void test(const char *regex) {
	regex_t preg;
	int errcode = regcomp(&preg, regex, REG_EXTENDED);
	if (errcode == 0) {
		printf("%s => Success\n", regex);
		regfree(&preg);
	}
	else {
		char errmsg[80];
		regerror(errcode, NULL, errmsg, 80);
		printf("%s => %s\n", regex, errmsg);
	}
}

int main() {
	test("(*\\.com)");
	test("(.*\\.com)");
	return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBda4MwFIavza84ODpiseJlobNXld2UXuyDDeYoEo82oIkkcQxG//pcktpu3V148p7nPQlbNIyN4w0XrB0qhDuFDX4mhzX5RdpUXP5HiovGMfIheQUGtaFMCm2AHUoFc6@J4IsE/rQ30NvDigRcGEClmLSaDCxjsuvprbuNwWdjeMjv9/nrU77b5JvIzdRALzMZpN4b9HYFU9NwpiFbw@PAGGpdiHDSuEFXXivEk9@RIwmw1egFflPr7XTztkzfp7wFUp3rYtg9b7fxlIphmXrtdfXsT@s5euo6EuLe25VcUL@0/6eQzosise@OQhebWHIFFZpBCUhX5DiO36xuy0aPi5eybX8A)

This should print something like:

```
(*\.com) => Invalid preceding regular expression
(.*\.com) => Success
```

Note that `(*\.com)` is a valid POSIX *basic* regex since an unescaped `(` matches a literal `(`. With basic regexes, a `*` at the beginning of a regex or parenthesized subexpression also matches a literal `*`.

Comment: With the same code, if we try the above pattern(what i have mentioned in  the question) , it fails to throw error, rather compiles successfully (no . before *)